# React Router V4 Route undefined (NoMatch) re-renders whole app and resets Redux state? ​

Tags: react-router-v4

While there is a similar question to this already it hasn't helped my issue.

I'm using React Router V4 with React and Redux and am finding for any undefined routes that the whole app is refreshed as is the redux state. Would this be working as designed and normal? I haven't been able to work out how this is happening but would appreciate any ideas. Is anyone else seeing this behaviour? Is it actually an issue? Thanks for your thoughts.

NGWP.

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? 'am finding for any undefined routes that the whole app is refreshed as is the redux state' What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi ... Here is a screen grab of what is happening. I hope this [Link​](https://mega.nz/#!CJABHaRI!aE4hSAAOs8Nb36J3tX-WLAgMhSottyczM-ioY5Bk‌​GDo) works for you. Hopefully you have VLC or something that can view the OGV format. You may see at 19 and 30 secs, the 'unknown' route resets the app and the Redux state. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks so much for taking a look

Comment: Further to this the MyApp.jsx that defines the routes can be found [here](https://github.com/notgoodwithpowertools/footy-tips-2/blob/master/src/MyApp.jsx) if you would care to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I dont have a tool to open OGV Format. For an easy to share screen recording have a look at this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hyfy-screen-video-recorde/kfhkikpdmehlpkaiplafjkaicdljldcf?hl=en

Comment: OK, have tried your suggested screen recorder which you can hopefully see [here](https://app.hyfy.io/v/abNmuyMNc2U/). See at 20secs where the state reloads with the /unknown route. It may not really be an issue and it isn't really effecting the app but am just curious as to why the state tree is reset with an unmatched route? I was expecting that the unmatched path collection to flag an unmatched route and redirect as needed which it does but it also resets the state and I can't seem to reconcile why? - Appreciate your thoughts.